# PHP MySQL subtracting 2 subqueries

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this statement to calculate the total of outbound minus inbound. for some reason, it is still giving me a result of zero.

```
<?php
$query = "select (select SUM(send) as SUN from money_transfers where trans_type = 'outbound'), (select SUM(send) as SUN1 from money_transfers where trans_type = 'inbound')";
$stmt = $sql->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo number_format($row['SUN'] - $row['SUN1'], 2);
?>
```

I tried subtracting directly within the query but still showing zero as result. What can I do to fix this query?

**UPDATE:**
I received this error for the above query:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '- (select SUM(send) as SUN1 from money_transfers where trans_type = 'inbound')' at line 1
```

Comment: What are the values of `SUN` and `SUN1`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas both positive values. the queries shown for each (outbound or inbound) work fine except when subtracting them.

Comment: Run `var_dump` on `$row`. Skip all formatting and math, just inspect the values to make sure that they are numeric and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the union syntaxis:

```
$query = "select SUM(send) as SUN from money_transfers where trans_type = 'outbound' UNION select SUM(send) as SUN1 from money_transfers where trans_type = 'inbound'";
```

Then Select the rows via while as each result will be one row

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine.

> ```
> CREATE TABLe money_transfers (send DECIMAL(10,2),trans_type varchar(20))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO money_transfers VALUES (10.1,'outbound'),(20.1,'inbound')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     (SELECT 
>             SUM(send) AS SUN
>         FROM
>             money_transfers
>         WHERE
>             trans_type = 'outbound') -
>     (SELECT 
>             SUM(send) AS SUN1
>         FROM
>             money_transfers
>         WHERE
>             trans_type = 'inbound') diff
> ```
>
> ```
> |   diff |
> | -----: |
> | -10.00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=839838b1c8d078660b2e27b96427b7e8)*

I would have guess you have a trans_type  with a space in it or anotehr character, you can try to TRIM(trans_type) and see if that helps